# НЕ работает функция swap()

Tags: java

Элементы не меняются местами. Почему?

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
int[] array= {80,2,56,0,78};
System.out.println(min(array));
}

 static void swap(int a, int b) {
int temp;
temp=a;
a=b;
b=temp;
}
 static int min (int [] arr) {
for (int i=0; i<arr.length-1;i++) {
    if(arr[i]>arr[i+1]) {
        swap(arr[i],arr[i+1]);
    }

}
return arr[0];

}
```

Comment: Потому что вы просто поменяли местами **значения** **локальных** переменных `a` и `b`, а не ячеек массива.

Comment: И не должно работать. Java все параметры передает по значению и для примитивных типов значение не изменится.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать применимо к ячейкам?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще искать минимум сортировкой это странный вариант решения задачи)
Вот ваш исправленный вариант:

```
static int min (int [] arr) {
    int temp;
for (int i=arr.length-1; i>0;i--) {
    if(arr[i]<arr[i-1]) {
        temp=arr[i];
        arr[i]=arr[i-1];
        arr[i-1]=temp;
    }

}
return arr[0];

}
```

Вот стандартный алгоритм поиска минимума:

```
static int min (int [] arr) {
    int temp=arr[0];
for (int i=0; i<arr.length;i++) {
    if(arr[i]<temp) {
        temp=arr[i];
    }
}
return temp;
}
```

Вот решение в стиле Java:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;


public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] array= {80,2,56,3,78};
        int min = Collections.min(Arrays.asList(array)); 
        int max = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(array)); 
        System.out.println("Minimum number of array is : " + min); 
        System.out.println("Maximum number of array is : " + max); 
    }


}
```